# Can we use z-test when the population standard deviation is known but the sample size < 30?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test

Let's say I know the population standard deviation, but the sample size is small (≤30). Can I use the z-test? The reason I ask is that I see two different statements.

1. We can use the z-test, if we know the population standard deviation AND the sample size is >30.
2. As long as we know the population standard deviation, we can use the z-test. The sample size does not matter (above or under 30).

What do you think and why? Thanks.

Comment: Yes if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for known $\sigma$. (Is it plausible to know the population standard deviation but not the mean?)  But if it has another distribution then it depends on whether a normal approximation would be close enough: in some cases it may be, while in others not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the hypothesis here? What does $X$ follow?

If $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2) $ with $\sigma$ being known, and $\mathcal H_0: \mu=\mu_0, $ then, of course, one can resort to the test statistic $$z:=\frac{\bar x-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt n}.\tag 1$$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the hypothesis I was referring to. So it does not matter even if n≤30, correct? Thanks.

Comment: This is an exact test. So, yes.

Comment: The question does not assume a Normal population distribution.

Comment: @whuber that's why I asked at the outset. What the specifics are. It seems it is indeed the case as OP said above.

Comment: I suspect the OP might not realize you made this extra (very strong) assumption.

Comment: I also bore the same concern as you (and as even Henry wrote). That's why both in Henry's comment and my answer, it was explicitly mentioned __if__ $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2), $ then.... Otherwise the question itself is ambiguous.